# Scrolling crashes program when scrolling through grid view

Tags: java, android

When I try to scroll through my word search, my program crashes throwing a null pointer exception.
However I have no idea why,

my grid view is created with an array

```
    String [] WordSearch =  new String[FormattedWords.length];

    for(int i = 1; i<FormattedWords.length ;i++)
    {
        WordSearch[i-1] = FormattedWords[i];
    }
```

, the logcat is giving me this also

```
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1331)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:331)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:243)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5036)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3193)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3138)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3463)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4203)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4243)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-17 14:19:37.623: E/AndroidRuntime(5969):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `WordSearch` that is being passed into the `ArrayAdapter` constructor? An Array of Strings?

Comment: Yes String [] WordSearch =  new String[FormattedWords.length];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does the for loop start at 1 and insert the data as it does? The `NullPointerException` is most likely caused by the for loop to insert Strings into the `WordSearch` Array.

eg.

Assuming FormattedWords is an Array (you are using the .length attribute), if `FormattedWords.length` is 3 and contains:

```
FormattedWords[0] = "a";
FormattedWords[1] = "b";
FormattedWords[2] = "c";
```

After the for loop `WordSearch` will contain:

```
WordSearch[0] = "b";
WordSearch[1] = "c";
WordSearch[2] = null;
```

Which is here your problem seems to be.

**EDIT**

If first value in FormattedWords is to be omitted then you should initiate `WordSearch` to size `FormattedWords.lenght - 1` to avoid the NPE.

eg.

```
String [] WordSearch =  new String[FormattedWords.length - 1];
```

Comment: I noticed I did have a null, but the reason is that in formatted words, the first value is blank, So I ant to skip over this value  and just get the rest

Answer (score 0):

if  value of `FormattedWords[i]` is equals to `null` means app will crashed when view comes front